# Starting thread in static block

Tags: java, multithreading, static

I wonder if the following code is OK:

```
public class MyClass {
...
  static {
    new MyClass().start();
  }

  private void start() {
  //running the thread
  }
}
```

I must add, I don't have access to something like main method, because this part of code is called from outside.

Does exists more sophisticated way of starting this thread?

Comment: The `static` code is executed when you create an object. So, instead, you can write that code in the Constructor.

Comment: @Hackerdarshi - Nope. `static` blocks are executed when your class is getting initialized

Comment: *"because this part of code is called from outside"* I would make it the responsibility of that outside caller to tell you when it's okay to begin processing (via a method call, even if a static one).

Comment: What is the entry point for the external caller?. It will have to invoke a method in your code right?

Comment: @TheLostMind Isn't that almost the same?

Comment: Other reasons for not starting it in the static block include the fact that you can't test `MyClass` (or any classes referencing `MyClass`) without also starting that thread.

Comment: @Hackerdarshi - Not even close :)

Comment: i wonder , like this there will be no reference for MyClass' instance in static block or anywhere else, so garbage collector would hunt it .

Comment: @Bolzano a running thread can't be garbage collected

Comment: Please clarify how "called from outside."

Comment: `public class MyClass {` does not extend Thread nor implement Runnable ... just in addition to what the others did say about when a static block is executed. I suspect OP has misconception about how threading works in Java.

Comment: Please provide some more information on your problem. Currently we are all guessing. What I understood is, that you are trying to start a new thread, but you don't need a new class without references to do so, you can basically start a new thread wherever you want (some limitations obviously :P).

Comment: @Hackerdarshi, a class constructor is called each time a new _instance_ of the class is created.  It's job is to put the fields of the new object into a known, state.  The `static` block is invoked one time only (assuming you're not doing something tricky with class loaders), and it's guaranteed that that invocation will happen before any outside code accesses the _class object_ or any of its members.  The job of the `static` block is to put the `static` fields of the class into a known state.

Comment: @jameslarge OK. I now see the difference. Earlier, whenever I created static blocks, I used to call the constructor of the class, and the block would execute. So I thought it was related to that. But  thanks to you, and of course, TheLostMind, I now know the reality. Thanks!